# LexisNexis SUDS SOAP Request

Tags: python, xml, authentication, soap, suds

I am also having SOAP problems. I am trying to implement an interface using python with SUDS.

I am trying to create an application that authenticates and searches LexisNexis in python. So if anyone knows if that has been implemented already that would also be great. I have searched around quite a deal, and did find this site: https://hkn.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dhsu/hacks.shtml, which is good, but does not have the SOAP code.

What I have done so far:

I know that the envelope should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Body xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <Authenticate xmlns="http://authenticate.authentication.services.v1.wsapi.lexisnexis.com">
    <authId>id</authId>
    <password>password</password>
  </Authenticate>
</soap:Body>
```

And I can build it (I think)

```
    from suds.sax.element import Element

    authentication = Element('Authenticate')
    authentication.set('xmlns','http://authenticate.authentication.services.v1.wsapi.lexisnexis.com')

    authId = Element('authId').setText('authId')

    password = Element('password').setText('password')

    authentication.append(authId)
    authentication.append(password)

    print authentication
```

That returns:

```
<Authenticate xmlns="http://authenticate.authentication.services.v1.wsapi.lexisnexis.com">
   <authId>authId</authId>
   <password>password</password>
</Authenticate>
```

However, I am not able to get the client to work. I am given this information:

Schema
 - Authentication.xsd

Target Namespace
 - http://authenticate.authentication.services.v1.wsapi.lexisnexis.com

Namespace Table

- http://authenticate.authentication.services.v1.wsapi.lexisnexis.com
- http://security.common.services.v1.wsapi.lexisnexis.com
- http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema

I am probably doing this wrong but I have tried:

```
client = Client('http://authenticate.authentication.services.v1.wsapi.lexisnexis.com')
```

and

```
imp = Import('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema',
                 location='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd')
imp.filter.add('http://security.common.services.v1.wsapi.lexisnexis.com')
wsdl_url = 'http://authenticate.authentication.services.v1.wsapi.lexisnexis.com'
client = Client(wsdl_url, doctor=ImportDoctor(imp))
```

However both resulted in

```
<urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known>
```

Sorry for being so newbie with SUDS, this is my first time and the LexisNexis api is pretty rough.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Your error has little to do with `suds`, and everything to do with the underlying `urllib` connection request:

```
<urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known>
```

This error is common when the hostname isn't correct, or there was simply no response from it. Here's the simpleist example:

```
import urllib
urllib.urlopen(u'http://authenticate.authentication.services.v1.wsapi.lexisnexis.com')
```

This fails too! Check your URL, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

LexisNexis gives API developers a WSDL file to use along with their username and password. You must make sure you're using this WSDL. To access a WSDL file locally using SUDS, enter the url as file://path/to/file.wsdl